# .Net resource files in separate language folders

Tags: c#, .net, localization, culture

Is it possible to have resource files in separate folders for each language as shown below?  I'd like all my English files in an "en" folder and all my Spanish files in an "es" folder. I have tried using the resources with both files in the main Resources folder (no subfolders), and it works correctly. However, when I have the files in separate "en" and "es" folders like in the image, I always get the English text even if my browser is set to display Spanish.

I've included file properties for each resource file along with the code I'm using to retrieve the value

[image]

[image]

[image]

```
var value = Language.Resources.ResourceManager.GetString(resourceName.Trim());
```

The auto-generated Resources.Designer.cs file includes the following code for the ResourceManager property.  Is that first parameter "ClientInterface.Resources.en.Resources" the reason why it's always giving me English?

```
        /// <summary>
    ///   Returns the cached ResourceManager instance used by this class.
    /// </summary>
    [global::System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableAttribute(global::System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableState.Advanced)]
    internal static global::System.Resources.ResourceManager ResourceManager {
        get {
            if (object.ReferenceEquals(resourceMan, null)) {
                global::System.Resources.ResourceManager temp = new global::System.Resources.ResourceManager("ClientInterface.Resources.en.Resources", typeof(Resources).Assembly);
                resourceMan = temp;
            }
            return resourceMan;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I think you need to remove part of namespace in auto-generated file.

Comment: @DzmitryTserakhau I have tried changing the namespace in the auto-generated file, and then whenever I call GetString(resourceName), it gives an error because it can't find the resources.

Comment: You need to move to Manual written Resources.Designer.cs in order to load right translation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see it like you need to write single Resource class manually and Custom Tool for Resources should be deleted.
And you need to write your own logic for receiving right ResourceManager.
This small sample without optimizations, but you can start with this.

> The auto-generated Resources.Designer.cs file includes the following
> code for the ResourceManager property. Is that first parameter
> "ClientInterface.Resources.en.Resources" the reason why it's always
> giving me English?

It's mostly because in autogenerated resource it is loading only english resource, but you need to write your logic, how to load your resource.
Example NamespaceToResources.**Language**.Resources
Or NamespaceToResources.**Culture**.Resources

In the next sample I'm loading Resource for current Culture

```
    /// <summary>
    ///   Returns the cached ResourceManager instance used by this class.
    /// </summary>
    [global::System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableAttribute(global::System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableState.Advanced)]
    internal static global::System.Resources.ResourceManager ResourceManager {
        get {
            return new global::System.Resources.ResourceManager($"ClientInterface.Resources.{Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture.Name.Replace("-", "_")}.Resource", typeof(Resource).Assembly);
        }
    }
```